# How to add fsck at boot like a regular service?

Tags: boot, rpm, startup, fsck, deb

I remember that certain distros, used to run `fsck` at boot after x boots, in a regular way.

How can be added to the boot process the `fsck` service to be

1. deployed in rpm distro/Fedora,RHEL,Oracle,Suse?
2. deployed in any distro/Arch,Debian,Slackware?

Thanks

Comment: [Read](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fsck)

Answer (score 2):

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/MyFsckScript.service` (feel free to replace *"MyFsckScript"*, don't change the rest) with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Filesytem check
Documentation=man:fsck(8)
Before=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/fsck REPLACETHISBYYOURDRIVE

[Install]
Alias=fsck.service
```

Now run: `systemctl enable fsck` and from now one it will be start at every boot.

Some "tweaking" of this answer will be needed for some distributions, but it should be a good start.

Comment: How do you make this service running before mounting the file systems ?

Comment: Try adding `Before=local-fs.target` to the service file.

Comment: Good idea, i edited the script

Comment: Maybe look into `systemd-fsck-root.service` for reference (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-fsck-root.service`). It says: `Before=local-fs.target shutdown.target`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the individual ext* file systems to require an `fsck` on every mount using

```
tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda1  # replace with each device name
```

`fsck.xfs` is a no-op. It just returns true. No `fsck.zfs` exists. I haven't checked for other file system types. No systemd service is required.

Comment: Although a nice feature for ext* filesystems, it's not portable. Every filesystem type uses different commands with different arguments for this. (And there are also types that don't support something like this at all)

Comment: @Garo I think you just repeated my answer. I gave something specific for ext* and said explicitly that this does not work for xfs or zfs. Other file systems may or may not have their own tools. What point are you trying to make here?

Comment: That the question never mentioned the filesystem type which means directly calling `tune2fs` has to be avoided.

Comment: @Garo `tune2fs` is useless _unless_ the OP has an ext* filesystem, possible since he never mentioned the filesystem type and I explicitly said this is for ext* file systems. If your point is that an suggestion should never be given is it is not universal, then I disagree. I gave an answer that would help in a large percentage of Linux systems and said that it would not help everywhere.

Comment: That is indeed my point, if a more universal answer is possible, that should be the preferred one. I try to avoid providing "will probably work"-answers when a "will even more likely work"-answer is available.

Comment: @Garo I did not say it "will probably work". I said that *if you have an ext filesystem*, this will work. If you don't, then this will not work. Where is the this "will even more likely work"  universal solution that you're referring to - I seem to have missed it. Setting up a systemd service is not universal - not all distros use systemd. And using `/bin/fsck` on an zfs, ntfs, btrfs, etc. will emit error messages, not really a solution. Does your answer work on many more file systems than mine?

Comment: You are right about systemd, it was wrong of me to assume it was present. But I would still go for `fsck`, with a addition how it works with a regular init. We should get rid of the "if you have"-part. No matter if it's "if you have extx" or "if you have systemd'. About the other filesystems: Most systems have a `fsck.fstype` script for a large amount of filesystems, even when many of them only contain `exit`. The idea is that in time they will do something useful. I have yet to encounter a system without a useful `fsck.extx` so using `fsck` is in the worst case still as good as `tune2fs`

Answer (score 0):

Systemd come with  `systemd-fsck`, it can be enabled to check the FS at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-fsck-root.service
```

or

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-fsck@.service
```

See [`man systemd-fsck`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-fsck@.service.8.html)